# How to fix error in web scraping with Python using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am really a beginner with Python, I want to web scraping and get structured data on the web using `BeautifulSoup4` but I get trouble and don't know how to solve it. 
This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.nba.com/players')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
players = soup.find(class_ ='row nba-player-index__row')
players_info = players.find_all(class_='nba-player-index__trending-item small-4 medium-3 large-2 team-okc-thunder')

players_name = [players_info.find(class_ ='nba-player-index__details').get_text() for player in players_info]
print(players_name)
```

And this my error

```
C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\WebScrape\Nba\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/WebScrape/Nba/Nba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/WebScrape/Nba/Nba.py", line 10, in <module>
    players_name = [players_info.find(class_ ='nba-player-index__details').get_text() for player in players_info]
  File "C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/WebScrape/Nba/Nba.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    players_name = [players_info.find(class_ ='nba-player-index__details').get_text() for player in players_info]
  File "C:\Users\moham\PycharmProjects\WebScrape\Nba\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2080, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Its always said call `'find_all() when you meant to call find() and attributes'`, I tried to change it into find() but still won't work. I try any solution but still won't work too, Hope someone help, thanks guys

Comment: You are accessing the wrong variable here `players_name = [players_info.find(`. It should be `players_name = [player.find(` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this instead:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

nba_players_url = 'https://www.nba.com/players'

nba_players_section = {'class': 'row nba-player-index__row'}
nba_info_section = {'class': 'nba-player-index__trending-item'}
nba_player_name_p = {'class': 'nba-player-index__name'}

r = requests.get(nba_players_url)

if r.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    players_section = soup.find('section', nba_players_section)

    players = players_section.find_all('section', nba_info_section)

    names = [
        player.find('p', nba_player_name_p).get_text(separator=' ')
        for player in players
    ]

    print(names)
```

But your life is going to be a lot easier with:

`nba_players_url = 'https://www.nba.com/players/active_players.json'`

That will give you a JSON with all the data you are looking for so there is no need to parse with BeautifulSoup.

Check it out:

```py
import requests
# just for printing players in a nice way
from pprint import pprint 

nba_players_url = 'https://www.nba.com/players/active_players.json'

r = requests.get(nba_players_url)

if r.ok:
    players = r.json()

    pprint(players, width=40)
```

And since we are on it, here is another option:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('https://www.nba.com/players/active_players.json')
```

And will have something like this:

```py
>>> df[['firstName', 'lastName', 'isAllStar']]
    firstName          lastName  isAllStar
0      Steven             Adams      False
1         Bam           Adebayo       True
2    LaMarcus          Aldridge      False
3     Nickeil  Alexander-Walker      False
4        Kyle         Alexander      False
..        ...               ...        ...
498  Thaddeus             Young      False
499      Trae             Young       True
500      Cody            Zeller      False
501      Ante             Zizic      False
502     Ivica             Zubac      False

[503 rows x 3 columns]


>>> df.info()
>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 503 entries, 0 to 502
Data columns (total 14 columns):
firstName       503 non-null object
lastName        503 non-null object
jersey          503 non-null int64
pos             503 non-null object
posExpanded     503 non-null object
heightFeet      503 non-null object
heightInches    503 non-null object
weightPounds    503 non-null object
personId        503 non-null int64
teamData        503 non-null object
isAllStar       503 non-null bool
orderChar       503 non-null object
playerUrl       503 non-null object
displayName     503 non-null object
dtypes: bool(1), int64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 51.7+ KB
>>>
```

Comment: thank you guys, its help me a lot.
can I ask again?
why I put a wrong variable on:
players_name = [players_info.find(. It should be players_name = [player.find(.
Where I am want to find is a name in players_info because there is a container of the name?
But thanks for changes the code, that's what I am looking for. 
And thanks for giving me another perspective using JSON, it's much easier I will learn it!.

Comment: Because the comprehension you are using will go over each `player` in `player_info` already, so `player` is the right variable to use. Anyway, avoid parsing with BeautifulSoup whenever you have a JSON option. Another advantage of JSON in your case is that the HTML version is a dynamic page and you (as you probably already know by now) will not get the complete players list.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the advice, sir! Umm, are you know or can you recommend me a website for learning web scraping with Python? I want learn it from basic haha.

Comment: I like the articles published by [Real Python](https://realpython.com). Check [Practical Introduction to Web Scraping in Python](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/) and [Beautiful Soup: Build a Web Scraper With Python](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/).

Comment: Sir, can I know, how you get  ```.JSON```  file on the website? thank you